# Looking for title of anthology about alien attack and rebuilding then future of Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens, technology

Aliens attack because we are close in technology to them but instead of completely wiping us out they set up some shields around a few small groups so the Earth can rebuild while they advance further beyond us.  They turn everything that is carbon-based and not shielded to ash.  One story followed a group that was shielded.  One followed some individuals who were in an underground bunker somewhere in the Midwest USA.  Some stories were set far after the attack and people had begun to develop technology like mind controlled spacecraft and teleportation.  I read this book in the 90s.

I remember one of the stories in the anthology was when humans were first gaining the ability to teleport and a guy thought he was dreaming he went to a far off planet and talked with a sentient white tree on a planet where only plant life existed but it was totally white colored leaves but then he later realizes he was actually there.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can add in any more details. That's a great start though!

Comment: This reminded me of the movie [Titan: A.E.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_A.E.) :) maybe not what you seel but worth seeing.